# Alfresco community 6 search (Solr) does not work properly

Tags: solr, alfresco

I deployed Alfresco community 6 (and all of its requirements such as search...) with its docker-compose file. but the search does not work properly. some times it works, some time it only works on the files that is uploaded using alfresco web UI (Share) and NOT on the files that is uploaded by Alfresco Rest API! and some time it seems the search capabilities are completely disabled (currently it even does not show some dashlets content in share like last modified, it shows Error loading items).

I just deployed Alfresco with its docker-compose file, without any modifications.

here is some logs from the Content Services and Solr.

```
solr6_1                  | 2020-05-04 05:55:12.361 ERROR (qtp915349526-17) [   x:alfresco] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall null:java.lang.NullPointerException
solr6_1                  |  at org.alfresco.solr.query.Solr4QueryParser.getContentStore(Solr4QueryParser.java:195)
solr6_1                  |  at org.alfresco.solr.query.Solr4QueryParser.<init>(Solr4QueryParser.java:168)
solr6_1                  |  at org.alfresco.solr.AlfrescoSolrDataModel.getLuceneQueryParser(AlfrescoSolrDataModel.java:1414)
solr6_1                  |  at org.alfresco.solr.query.AlfrescoLuceneQParserPlugin$AlfrescoLuceneQParser.parse(AlfrescoLuceneQParserPlugin.java:85)
solr6_1                  |  at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:168)
solr6_1                  |  at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:161)
solr6_1                  |  at org.apache.solr.handler.component.AlfrescoSearchHandler.handleRequestBody(AlfrescoSearchHandler.java:323)
solr6_1                  |  at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:173)
solr6_1                  |  at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2477)
solr6_1                  |  at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:723)
solr6_1                  |  at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:529)
solr6_1                  |  at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:361)
solr6_1                  |  at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:305)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
solr6_1                  |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
solr6_1                  |  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
solr6_1                  | 
alfresco_1               | 2020-05-04 05:55:12,364  ERROR [extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception from executeScript: 04040012 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 04040113 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/collaboration/tagQuery.get.js': 04040112 Failed to execute search: PATH:"/app:company_home//*" AND ASPECT:"{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}taggable" -ASPECT:"{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}workingcopy"
alfresco_1               | org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 04040012 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 04040113 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/collaboration/tagQuery.get.js': 04040112 Failed to execute search: PATH:"/app:company_home//*" AND ASPECT:"{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}taggable" -ASPECT:"{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}workingcopy"
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:1139)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:171)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:519)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:450)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:595)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:664)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScriptInternal(RepositoryContainer.java:435)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:315)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:399)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:210)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.AlfrescoWebScriptServlet.service(AlfrescoWebScriptServlet.java:43)
alfresco_1               |  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
alfresco_1               |  at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor442.invoke(Unknown Source)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:170)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:225)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:47)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
alfresco_1               |  at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor420.invoke(Unknown Source)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:191)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:47)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.module.aosmodule.service.ContextRootFilter.doFilter(ContextRootFilter.java:93)
alfresco_1               |  at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor420.invoke(Unknown Source)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:191)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:47)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:68)
alfresco_1               |  at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor420.invoke(Unknown Source)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:191)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:47)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.ClearSecurityContextFilter.doFilter(ClearSecurityContextFilter.java:53)
alfresco_1               |  at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor420.invoke(Unknown Source)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:191)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:47)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
alfresco_1               | Caused by: org.alfresco.scripts.ScriptException: 04040113 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/collaboration/tagQuery.get.js': 04040112 Failed to execute search: PATH:"/app:company_home//*" AND ASPECT:"{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}taggable" -ASPECT:"{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}workingcopy"
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:211)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.execute(ScriptServiceImpl.java:219)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.executeScript(ScriptServiceImpl.java:181)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryScriptProcessor.executeScript(RepositoryScriptProcessor.java:109)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.executeScript(AbstractWebScript.java:1376)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:86)
alfresco_1               |  ... 107 more
alfresco_1               | Caused by: org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 04040112 Failed to execute search: PATH:"/app:company_home//*" AND ASPECT:"{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}taggable" -ASPECT:"{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}workingcopy"
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.Search.queryResultMeta(Search.java:1127)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.Search.query(Search.java:986)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.Search.query(Search.java:970)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.Search.query(Search.java:929)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.Search.luceneSearch(Search.java:353)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.Search.luceneSearch(Search.java:338)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
alfresco_1               |  at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:138)
alfresco_1               |  at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:226)
alfresco_1               |  at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:45)
alfresco_1               |  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_collaboration_tagQuery_get_js_8._c_tagQuery_1(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/collaboration/tagQuery.get.js:86)
alfresco_1               |  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_collaboration_tagQuery_get_js_8.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/collaboration/tagQuery.get.js)
alfresco_1               |  at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName0(OptRuntime.java:87)
alfresco_1               |  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_collaboration_tagQuery_get_js_8._c_script_0(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/collaboration/tagQuery.get.js:170)
alfresco_1               |  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_collaboration_tagQuery_get_js_8.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/collaboration/tagQuery.get.js)
alfresco_1               |  at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:409)
alfresco_1               |  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3566)
alfresco_1               |  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_collaboration_tagQuery_get_js_8.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/collaboration/tagQuery.get.js)
alfresco_1               |  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_collaboration_tagQuery_get_js_8.exec(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/collaboration/tagQuery.get.js)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.executeScriptImpl(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:509)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:207)
alfresco_1               |  ... 112 more
alfresco_1               | Caused by: org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException: 04040111 Request failed 500 /solr/alfresco/alfresco?wt=json&fl=DBID%2Cscore&rows=1000&df=TEXT&start=0&locale=af&alternativeDic=DEFAULT_DICTIONARY&fq=%7B%21afts%7DAUTHORITY_FILTER_FROM_JSON&fq=%7B%21afts%7DTENANT_FILTER_FROM_JSON
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.AbstractSolrQueryHTTPClient.postQuery(AbstractSolrQueryHTTPClient.java:108)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.postSolrQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:1115)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.executeQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:582)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryLanguage.executeQuery(SolrQueryLanguage.java:52)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrSearchService.query(SolrSearchService.java:354)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.search.SearcherComponent.query(SearcherComponent.java:84)
alfresco_1               |  at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor623.invoke(Unknown Source)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.SubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(SubsystemProxyFactory.java:79)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
alfresco_1               |  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.query(Unknown Source)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.SearchServiceSubSystemDelegator.query(SearchServiceSubSystemDelegator.java:133)
alfresco_1               |  at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor623.invoke(Unknown Source)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
alfresco_1               |  at net.sf.acegisecurity.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:80)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:53)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:166)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
alfresco_1               |  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.query(Unknown Source)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.Search.queryResultMeta(Search.java:1016)
alfresco_1               |  ... 135 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was resolved. It was a stupid problem. the search functionality of alfresco **depends on locale**! the browser's locale I was using for search was set to a different locale than the of files that were uploaded by java code.